# TypeError: (void 0) is not a constructor in webpack and react production mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, three.js, orbitcontrols

**Getting error in webpack react production mode.**
Working fine in development mode.
I am using three.js and the error is coming
 `this.orbiter = new THREE.OrbitControls(this, this.camera, this.canvasContainer, this);`
in production mode this will change to
 `this.orbiter = new (void 0)(this,this.camera,this.canvasContainer,this),`
and will get this error.

**I am using react@16, webpack@4.44 and three@0.112.1**

```
TypeError: (void 0) is not a constructor
    at CU.init (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:397:128884)
    at CU.componentDidMount (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:397:120022)
    at is (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:83371)
    at fl (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:101245)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:385:3844)
    at Br (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:45023)
    at pl (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:97717)
    at Qs (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:93871)
    at vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:377:45314
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (vk-ui-prod.c44e9123eae95b092aa3.min.js:385:3844)
e
```

I have tried to export OrbitControls from JSM file and install seperate npm packages as well but nothing works.